# Type of itertools.product argument?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to use python `itertools.product()`. What type of input does it take? I want to input just 1 variable. How should that be structured?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
itertools.product(a,b) # this works.
```

Is it possible to only pass 1 argument? ex:

```
c = (a,b)
itertools.product(c)
```

Comment: Did you a) check the documentation and b) try it?

Comment: Use `*` for [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) e.g. `itertools.product(*c)`

Answer (score 1):

Compare with `itertools.chain`

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
c = [a, b]

itertools.chain(a, b)             # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
itertools.chain(c)                # [1, 2, 3, 4] [5, 6, 7, 8]

itertools.chain(*c)               # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
# or chain specifically has a more-legible version of this
itertools.chain.from_iterable(c)  # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Note that `some_function(*[a, b, c])` is the same as `some_function(a, b, c)`. This is called argument unpacking.